# Providing custom metric via oozie-client or REST API

Tags: java, oozie

Is it possible to return simple processing result either via java oozie-client or REST API? I've been analyzing java docs but couldn't find any suitable place to store such information.

Possible scenario: java client triggers job defined as oozie workflow via oozie-client API. Several datastores are produced. Last action of workflow definition generates simple JSON report containing set of metrics based on those datastores. I am looking for a way to provide this report back to client as `String` output parameter.

I can obviously write this as JSON file in HDFS but I would prefer to keep this client behind the oozie-client API.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I picked: returning custom metrics via `WorkflowAction#data` and marking action with `</capture-output>` in `workflow.xml` definition.

Data is in fact `java.util.Properties` dump so all the metrics are returned in `key=value` format.